# How to notate the $xy$-plane (and the half-space above it).

Tags: soft-question, notation

I am looking for a way to notate the set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given as $\Big\{ (x,y,z): z = 0 \Big\}$, ie, the $xy$-plane (or the plane $z=0$). I want a notation which may also work with notating the $z\geq 0$ half-space. Some ideas I had are:

- $Z_0$ and $Z_0^+$ to indicate the plane and the half-space respectively but this sits a bit unwell in my stomach.
- Simply $Z$ and $Z^+$ but this seems too ambiguous.
- $XY$ for the plane and $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ for the half-space but then there is no relation between the two and this bothers me a little.

What would you pick to notate them?

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb{R}^3_{z=0}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3_{z\geq0}$?

Comment: @dromastyx I hadn't tried it beacuse I thought it may look too crowded. Now that I see it, it looks ok. Maybe I will use this one!

Comment: I think that this question is too opinion-based to have an authoritative answer, hence I am going to give my opinion here and vote to close.  In complex analysis, the (upper) half-plane is often denoted by $\mathbb{H}$.  By analogy, I think that using a blackboard bold H for a half-space makes sense, perhaps with decoration.  For example, $\mathbb{H}_z$ or $\mathbb{H}_z^+$ for the positive $z$ half-space.  Perhaps $\mathbb{P}_z$ for the plane $\{z=0\}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2\times \{0\}$ for the first, $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ for the second, or black board H, as Xander said

Comment: Thanks all for your comments! Yes this is very opinion based, I really just wanted some ideas. I think I'm gonna go with the notation suggested by @J.-E. Pin in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you may introduce the projections $\pi_i: {\Bbb R}^3 \to {\Bbb R}$ defined by $\pi(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_i$.
Then the $xy$-plane is $\pi_3^{-1}(0)$ and the half-plane is $\pi_3^{-1}([0, + \infty])$. You may also use the following notation:
$$
P_0 = \{(x,y,z) \in {\Bbb R}^3 \mid z = 0\} \quad \text{and}\quad P_{\geqslant 0} = \{(x,y,z) \in {\Bbb R}^3 \mid z \geqslant 0\}\
$$